# Trying to understand some exposition on the 2nd derivative

Tags: calculus

I struggle to understand non geometric (i.e. picture) based mathematical exposition, but I realize that I will need to understand it eventually. Part of my confusion lies in that I am not always sure what the symbols mean. I was trying to understand why the 2nd derivative test works, and after googling came across [this](http://oregonstate.edu/instruct/mth251/cq/Stage7/Lesson/second.i.html) website with the following statement:

> Suppose that f does NOT have a local minimum at x = c. Then we cannot have the first derivative of f(x) negative on some interval (c - d,c) AND positive on some interval (c, c + d). Thus one of these two conditions fails.

My understanding of the symbols used are as follows:

- f is an arbitrary function
- x = c is referring to the y-axis being moved along the x-axis by some real number c
- d is also some arbitrary real number, i think

That being said, I do not understand the part of the statement which has negative on some interval (c - d, c), and being positive on some interval (c, c + d). What is (c - d, c) supposed to mean? Particularly, what is c - d in this context trying to tell me? Whats the best way to think about such statements?

Comment: $x=c$ does not refer to the $x$-axis - rather, it refers to the $y$-axis translated to the left by $c$ units on the $x$ axis.

Comment: thank you for the clarification

Comment: is it best practice to update my question with new knowledge gained such as rewording my understanding of x = c now?

Comment: Yes, it is.${}{}$

Comment: ok, thanks. I updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interval $(c-d, c)$ is the open interval $\{x \mid c-d < x < c \}$.  That is, all values of x between (but not including) the values $c-d$ and $c$.  Likewise $(c, c+d)$ is the open interval $\{x \mid c < x < c+d\}$.

If the curve is continuous and has no local minimum at $x=c$ then the gradient of the curve (the derivative) must have the same sign on either side near that point.  It cannot have a negative slope on one side and a positive slope on the other.

(Of course this only works for arbitrarily *small* $d$; sufficiently so that there are *no* minima in either intervals.)

---

It's more conventional to separate the bounds by double dots, like so $(a..b)$, to be clear that you're describing an interval rather than a coordinate pair (or a series).

For a closed interval, one uses 'square-braces' on the closed end. Such as $[a..b) \equiv \{x | a \leq x < b\}$.

Comment: thanks for the convention clarification, i did indeed think that it was describing a coordinate pair the entire time.

Comment: Also, when I see c - d in exposition like this, its just assumed that d < c? Likewise with c + d?

Comment: I picked this answer because it helped me best understand the chain of reasoning of how not having a local minimum (and being able to deduce what that actually meant from the statement as well) followed into the positive and negative derivatives on those intervals

Answer (score 1):

I take it that you are asking about the meaning of the interval $(c-d,c)$. Consider the point $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Let us draw the real line and select the point $c$. Put two sliders on this point, and move one by $d$ units to the left. The region between the two - not including $c$ and $c-d$ itself - forms the open interval $(c-d,c)$.

About the part where $f^{'}$ is negative on $(c-d,c)$ and $f^{}$ is positive on $(c,d+c)$. Drawing out the graph shows that in the interval $(c-d,c+d)$, the graph is locally a function of the form $f(x)=x^{2k}$. Also, you see that at the point $c$, the first derivative changes sign from $-$ to $+$. Using the graph shows that $f$ has a local maximum at $c$. This is the geometric interpretation of first derivatives, second derivatives, e.t.c.

Comment: after reading your first paragraph, i realized that I was considering the notation (c - d, c) to be a point and not an interval, even though it specifically said interval. Do you happen to have any source that talks about graphing the (c - d, c + d)? I think thats interesting and would like to learn more about it.

Comment: @user1489829 Ah, yes. That's a common mistake, one which I myself made the first time I studied it, which was over 5 years ago.